# Qual a diferença entre props e state em React.js?

Tags: javascript, react

Qual a diferença entre `props` e `state` em [react.js](/questions/tagged/react.js), qual as diferenças e como devem ser usados?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

De maneira resumida pode dizer-se:

- `props` - valores herdados
- `state` - valores internos do componente

O conceito é: `state` deve servir para guardar valores/estados da aplicação que mudam com o uso da mesma, para guardar uma alteração de estado que pode ter efeito na renderização do próprio componente, ser passado a um componente filho como `prop`, ou que deve ser passado a algo externo à aplicação. As `props` são valores estáticos, ou que no contexto de um Componente sejam estáticos, daí serem `props` e não `state` para separar conceptualmente.

`state` pode ser importado de `props` dentro do Componente, mas não pode ser herdado do componente pai.

Exemplo:

```js
class Mostrador extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const frase = this.props.valor ? 'O valor escolhido foi o ' : '...nenhum valor escolhido...';
    return (
      <p>
        {frase}
        <span>{this.props.valor || ''}</span>
      </p>
    );
  }
}
class Botao extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button  type="button"  onClick={this.props.onButtonClick.bind(this.props.nr)}>
        {"Eu sou o botão nr: " + this.props.nr}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      escolhido: 0
    }
  }
  handleClick(nr) {
    this.setState({escolhido: nr});
  }
  render() {
    const botoes = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(
      nr => (<Botao key={nr} nr={nr} onButtonClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, nr)}/>)
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Clica nos botões!</h1>
        <section>
          {botoes}
        </section>
        <section>
          <Mostrador valor={this.state.escolhido} />
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
button {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
p {
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```

#### A lógica do exemplo é:

- Componente pai (`App`)
- *n* botões
- mostrador

O componente pai `App` funciona como controlador. Ele guarda no seu `state` o estado de qual o numero escolhido, e tem também a função chamada quando o botão é clicado. O `state` é dinamico pois muda de valor cada vez que um botão fôr clicado.

O componente `Botao` é um simples botão. Ele não herda nada do `state` de `App`. o numero que lhe corresponde é guardado diretamente no `.bind()` da função `handleClick`. A unica coisa que ele herda é um ponteiro para a função a ser chamada quando ele receber um clique.

O componente `Mostrador` herda o `state` de `App`, e usa-o internamente como `prop`. Assim, cada vêz que o  `state` de `App` mudar, o [react.js](/questions/tagged/react.js) chama o `render()` de `App` que passa o `state.escolhido` ao `Mostrador` como `prop`, `prop.valor`. Esse numero é então usado no `.render()` de `Mostrador`.

---

**Notas:**

**a)** Em casos onde os dados da aplicação sejam geridos externamente (por biblioteca externa como MobX ou variantes de Flux) o `state` deve limitar-se a ações e mudanças de estado de UI, e não de dados da aplicação.

**b)** É possivel setar o state de fora do Componente mas é anti-padrão, por isso não refiro no exemplo.